# Pass MemoryStream object to .NET 4.0from .NET 2.0 web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

In my MVC3 app, i am consuming asmx web services written in .net 2.0. Everything is working fine until i ran into sending/receiving MemoryStream and FileStream oblects. This Is a sample of what i'm running into. Heres the asmx code (.net 2.0):

```
    [WebMethod]
    public FileStream testing()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.txt", FileMode.CreateNew);
        return fs;
    }
```

I build it and then consume it in my MVC3 (.net 4.0) app:

```
        Service1.Service1 service1 = new Service1.Service1();
        System.IO.FileStream fs = service1.testing();
```

When I try to run this, I get this error:

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 
'MvcApplication1.Service1.FileStream' to 'System.IO.FileStream'
```

Even if i set my variable to type MvcApplication1.Service1.FileStream, I cant do what i need to with this FileStream object like the FileStream Read and Close functions etc. I get the same thing with MemoryStream objects too. Whats is the problem and how can i make this work? Thanks

Comment: Sending streams in ASMX web services [is not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903182/wcf-streaming-on-asmx). WCF does, however.

Comment: OUCH! Thanks for the info. Of course my goal is to have users download/upload documents. How can i do that with asmx services? Theres got to be a way

Comment: Generate the file on the fly store it on a CDN or cloud and return the users the url for it to download.

Comment: The files are being stored on a share thats not accessible to the user. Oh well. I'll see what other options i have.